# ASP.NET MVC jQuery Autocomplete HtmlHelper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I was thinking about writing universal HtmlHelper for jQuery autocomplete wire up for ASP.NET MVC and I would like to know first if something like that already exists.

Also do you think it even makes sense to write one because so far even by myself I had 4 different scenarios for which I had to customize it (data from the datastore is almost always different and I always need some custom display of it, sometimes ID is the key, sometimes not)?

How do Ruby guys do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codevoyeur.com/Articles/10/ASP.NET-MVC-HtmlHelper-Extensions-for-jQuery-AutoComplete.aspx) you have an example of such a helper. I found it very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't spend time developing a general solution of this, since it's already very easy to wire up. And, as you said, there's always different scenarios to cover.

Oh, and I'm a .net-guy, so don't ask me about the Ruby-part :)

Answer (score 0):

Even being a very old question I've come to this today, and searching for others options I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/789425/Auto-Complete-in-ASP-NET-MVC), and maybe it could help.

I think it's a good autocomplete helper implementation, but needs some improvements, mainly on the URL creation using those enums. Still worth a look and save some time.